# Robb Stark house card. Need some help understanding what it can do

Tags: game-of-thrones

Can the house card "Robb Stark" retreat the losers troops to a place that is not adjacent to the losers troops? Can he move the routing troops back two countries or past a river/ocean? In other words does the rule for retreating to an adjacent area still apply.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the exact wording on the card for those of us without the board game right in front of us.

Answer (score 3):

Normal retreat. No jumping rivers, no going two countries. Can use ships.

Optimal usage : Attack a big force with Robb to win, retreat them somewhere where you can attack them with one footman and slay the lot.